# Monitoring progress of server tasks via TCP or HTTP

Tags: python, http, tcp, server

I'm working on a client-server application in which the client sends some data (JSON format) to a server to be processed. The process takes a long time to complete, hence I like to modify the server code in a way that sends some logs on the progress of the algorithm back to the client. I think I have two options to do this:

1. Using a TCP server to send logs back to the client.
2. Using an HTTP server and regularly send a request from client to the server to return the status of the tasks.

My questions are

1. In general which method is preferable? When should I use the first method and when the second one?
2. Are there any other methods to send back server logs to the client?

I use python as the programming language, the server is written using flask and my algorithm that should be run on the server uses multiprocessing to increase the speed.

My client is a separate python application and is not in browser.

Comment: Option 2 seems perfectly reasonable and can use normal ajax GET to retrieve status. Maybe the POST request which starts the operation gets a link back to the operation-specific https (of course)  status enquiry URL and then the browser polls it to 100% No need to adopt different technology.

Comment: @barny Thank you for your comment. I have my own python based client and don't use the browser. Also, I'm relatively new to server programming. Should the client send the request for new status regularly (for example every 500ms) or there is a better way to poll the status?

Comment: If displaying to the user then maybe every 1s (make it configurable) - and the server by indicating progress means the user can get a progress bar if that’s what you want.

Comment: But are you using http at all - if not then why bother using http or websockets for the progress indication.

Comment: @barny The current code that I've written uses http. I can change the connection protocol. The only thing that matters is that I should be able to run the server on a remote computer and it should handle a couple of users. Based on your comment I think sticking to http is a better option (Am I correct?).

Comment: “Am I correct?” I don’t know, but using existing http for progress tracking appears to be lower cost and risk than adding use of a different protocol overlaid on e.g. websockets just for progress tracking. NOTE that if you used websockets _you_ would have to implement the protocol that you use to query progress. That sounds like more work that simply making more http requests.

Comment: @barny Thank you for helpful comments (It was more like an answer than a comment). Why using websockets requires queries from client to server to check the progress? Can't the server just send the progress on a regular basis to the client without receiving any query from client?

Comment: Yes of course you could implement the progress protocol like that. Note the “you” in that statement, and note that this would involve extra code/brain effort beyond making http GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the second question:

I think the best solution here would be to use the [Websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). The benefit here is that you can incorporate it with a flask, for example, using this library [Flask-SocketIO](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO).

Websockets were designed to work on top of the HTTP/HTTPS. In the case of https - the communication is already encrypted via SSL/TLS, so instead of the standard TCP, you can use this security measure. Another thing is that when you would like to use a browser as a client. You cannot open "raw" socket in the browser.